# How to Execute Python File In Unix Find Command

Tags: python-2.7, unix, find

Okay. So I lets say that I am in the main directory of my computer. How can I search for a file.py and execute it with Unix in one line? Two lines is okay but we are assuming we do not know the file path.

Its a simple question but I am unable to find an answer

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Per kojiro's comment, a better method is to use the `-exec` argument to find.

```
$ find ./ -name 'file.py' -exec python '{}' \;
```

The manpage for find explains its usage better than I can, see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) under `-exec command ;`. But in short it will call `command` for each result with any arguments up to the `\;` and replacing `'{}'` with the file path of the result.

Also in the man page for `find`, it's worth looking at the notes relating to the `-print` and `-print0` flags if you're using the below approach.

**Original Answer**

Does something like the following do what you want?

```
$ cd /path/to/dir/
$ find ./ -name 'file.py' | xargs -L 1 python
```

which is a pretty useful pattern where

```
find ./ -name 'file.py'
```

will list all the paths to files with names matching `file.py` in the current directory or any subdirectory.

Pipe the output of this into `xargs` which passes each line from its stdin as an argument to the program given to it. In this case, python. However we want to execute python once for every line given to xargs, from the [wikipedia article for xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs)

> one can also invoke a command for each line of input at a time with -L 1

However, this will match all files under the current path that are named 'file.py'. You can probably limit this to the first result with a flag to `find` if you want.

Comment: Consider using the `-exec` arg to `find` instead of `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a better way. Will update the answer include that.